# About the usage of Python-apt

Tags: apt, package-management, python

my goal is to collect different executable files with the same source code in all Linux distros and all architectures,  e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 12 in amd64 and i386, as much as possible, and for scientific purposes only.

I don't know if there are any neat ways to do that, I'm currently trying to set a  source.list cache in python-apt (so that others won't be influenced using apt), and then download executables and source codes of packages listed by my previous work.

My python-apt version is 2.4.0, and when I run the codes below, it shows the GPG public key error; after I added '[trusted=yes]' into the source, the package_list has no 'vim', it seems like it cached nothing.

It would be grateful if you could help me with this.
Best regards.

```
with open('/home/etc/apt/source.list', 'w') as f:
    f.write('deb https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free \n')
cache = apt.Cache(rootdir=os.getcwd(), memonly=True)
# cache._run_fetcher(apt_pkg.Acquire(apt.progress.text.AcquireProgress()))
cache.update( sources_list='/tmp/source_2.list')
package_list = ['vim']  
print(cache.keys())
for package_name in package_list:
....
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @guiverc I would be inclined to leave this question open because the author specifically mentioned Ubuntu 18.04. That was just an example suggests that this question was intended to be relevant to other Ubuntu versions generally.

Comment: @karel the example code and `https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ bullseye` was the '*clincher*' for my decision... as that's not a Ubuntu release..  (*multiple references to off-topic Debian, with a single reference to 18.04 that is on-topic as if to circumnavigate rules...*)

Comment: I also saw the single reference to 18.04, but since it was prefaced by "e.g." I interpreted that as being relevant to other Ubuntu versions generally, like the rmadison tool which is provided by the devscripts package in Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel  close-vote removed; the `python-apt` version mentioned matches up with Ubuntu (*jammy* or *kinetic*), closer than it does Debian in a quick query... so taking that as another reference to on-topic Ubuntu.

Comment: My bad, the version of my python-apt is '2.4.0+ubuntu1' to be specific. Thanks tons guys

Answer (score 1):

problem solved, if you encounter the same issue, you can try this out:
and remember to check the 'rootdir' should contains your sources.list

```
with open('/home/BinDiff/etc/apt/sources.list', 'w') as f:
    f.write('deb [trusted=yes] https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ bullseye main ')

cache = apt.Cache(rootdir=os.getcwd(), memonly=True)
cache._run_fetcher(apt_pkg.Acquire(apt.progress.text.AcquireProgress()),allow_unauthenticated=True)
```